# FloatingActionButton do not jump up under CoordinatorLayout Android

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying the FloatingActionButton jump up effect (Under CoordiantorLayout). The snackbar is called when Fab is touched. However the Fab does not jump up. Where do I mess up?

```
fab.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ViewCompat.animate(fab).rotation(r).withLayer().setDuration(1000).setInterpolator(interpolator).start();
            r+=45f;
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.relative_layout), "Test", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            return false;
        }
    });
```

The layout file

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FF00"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:background="#00FFFF"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the size of your `CoordinatorLayout` is `wrap_content`/`wrap_content`, so it is no bigger than the FAB.

Also, the `View` that you are passing to `Snackbar.make()` is outside the `CoordinatorLayout` anyway. `Snackbar` is going to look for a `CoordinatorLayout` at the level of your `RelativeLayout` and above, and so `Snackbar` will not find your `CoordinatorLayout`.

I suggest that you change your layout so that your `CoordinatorLayout` wraps around your `RelativeLayout`.

For example, this layout has a FAB on the lower right, and the FAB will slide out of the way if I provide the `ListView` as the first parameter to `Snackbar.make()`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    />

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh_black_24dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```